# Undefined error $_POST index

Tags: php, post

Can someone please explain what does undefined error means on this link?

Whenever i visit my forum page it does gives me this error undefined index fpost.

fpost is the text area holder for the message. Obviously there is still no content in fpost when you initially visit the page, i don't know why it's propmting an error i already have `if( isset($_POST['fpost']) && $_POST['fpost']!=='' )` condition to eliminate the error but it's not working...

I haven't even click the post button to begin with

> **Notice:** Undefined index: fpost in ... on line 231

I don't understand the words people are using, can you please explain it in laymans term where beginners will understand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the code and provide more description explanation of the error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Next time you need to post code or error messages just paste them here as *text*. Taking a screenshot to upload it to a third-party server and linking it (not even embedding it) is wasting everybody's time, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have set `name="fpost"` for text area holder for the message.

If you didn't it will through undefined variable error.

Comment: i already solved it. just avoid initializing variables and setting it to post value. Thanks :)

Comment: @user2610699 Great if you solved it yourself , keep it up.